# getting error as Exception in Tkinter callback and Attribute Error: 'NoneType' Object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, googletrans

I am trying to create a translator with help of Tkinter and googletrans library but getting following error and I am confuse as I am not sure is this error due to library or a mistake from my side.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from googletrans import  Translator,LANGUAGES

def change(text="Type", src="English", dest="Hindi"):
    text1=text
    src1=src
    dest1=dest
    trans= Translator()
    trans1= trans.translate(text,src=src1,dest=dest1)
    return trans1

def data():
    s = comb_sor.get()
    d = comb_dest.get()
    msg= Sor_txt.get(1.0,END)
    textget = change(text= msg, src=s, dest=d)
    dest_txt.delete(1.0,END)
    dest_txt.insert(END,textget)

root = Tk()
root.title("Translator")
root.geometry("500x700")
root.config(bg='#f1f3f5')

lab_txt=Label(root, text="Translator", font=("Inter", 30, "bold"), bg="#f1f3f5", fg="#495057")
lab_txt.place(x=100, y=40, height=50, width=300)

frame = Frame(root).pack(side=BOTTOM)

lab_txt=Label(root, text="Source Text", font=("Inter", 16, "bold"), bg="#f1f3f5", fg="#495057")
lab_txt.place(x=100, y=100, height=30, width=300)
Sor_txt = Text(frame, font=("Inter", 18, "bold"), bg="#f1f3f5", wrap=WORD)
Sor_txt.place(x=10, y=130, height=150, width=480)

list_text = list(LANGUAGES.values())

comb_sor = ttk.Combobox(frame, value=list_text)
comb_sor.place(x=10, y=300, height=40, width=150)
comb_sor.set("English")

button_change = Button(frame, text="Translate", relief=RAISED, command=data)
button_change.place(x=170, y=300, height=40, width=150)

comb_dest = ttk.Combobox(frame, value=list_text)
comb_dest.place(x=330, y=300, height=40, width=150)
comb_dest.set("English")

lab_txt=Label(root, text="Destination Text", font=("Inter", 16, "bold"), bg="#f1f3f5", fg="#495057")
lab_txt.place(x=100, y=360, height=30, width=300)
dest_txt = Text(frame, font=("Inter", 18, "bold"), bg="#f1f3f5", wrap=WORD)
dest_txt.place(x=10, y=400, height=150, width=480)

root.mainloop()
```

Please find the snippet of error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "e:\AWS Cloud Practioner\Translator\main.py", line 17, in data
    textget = change(text= msg, src=s, dest=d)
  File "e:\AWS Cloud Practioner\Translator\main.py", line 10, in change
    trans1= trans.translate(text,src=src1,dest=dest1)
  File "C:\Users\ghago\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 182, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ghago\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
  File "C:\Users\ghago\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\ghago\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
    code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I tries installing mttinker (new to me) and changing google translate version as well but no solution is found

Comment: Please copy and paste your error into the question, instead of just leaving a link. For more info, go to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you tried printing the parameters and seeing if they are not `None`?

Comment: No, I have not tried it yet, can you tell me which parameter you are talking about

Comment: Why do you have duplicated `lab_txt`? Use different variable

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in `googletrans`. You can find its [description on GitHub](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/366).  At this moment, you have to install a future version of that module to be able to run it.

In your environment, you have to run this command to upgrade `googletrans` as described in [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/280#issuecomment-1003178295):

```
pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1
```

After installing that version, you should be able to run your code without this error message.

---

But your will see another malfunction when you will run your code. You should change your code in the function `change()` from `return trans1` to `return trans1.text`. It should look a little bit like:

```py
def change(text="Type", src="English", dest="Hindi"):
    text1=text
    ⋮
    trans1= trans.translate(text,src=src1,dest=dest1)
    return trans1.text
```